# How to use compiled inserts in Slick 2.1.0?

Tags: scala, slick

[Slick 2.1.0 changelog](http://slick.typesafe.com/news/2014/08/04/slick-2.1.0-release.html) mentions that ability to compile insert queries was added. At the same time [documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/queries.html#compiled-queries) still states that compiled queries could be used only for querying, updating and deleting.

So, how do you actually define compiled insert queries, specifically when case class is used as an argument for insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't say only :). But it doesn't mention insert, correct. Docs seem to be outdated there.

This all works:

```
val someQuery = someTable.filter(...).map(...)
val someQueryCompiled = Compiled{ someQuery }

someQueryCompiled.run( ... )
someQueryCompiled.insert( ... )
someQueryCompiled.delete( ... )
someQueryCompiled.update( ... )
```